# Custom post type loop split/ordered by taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I'm setting up a FAQs page. I've created a custom post type called "Questions" with a custom taxonomy called "Sections".
Within the sections I've created several categories:

- General
- Rules
- Payment

...etc

There's 90 questions all categorised within one of the sections. I'd like to output the loop/query so that each question sits under its section heading. If new sections or questions are added they will automatically get generated in the loop.

The output would be something like this:

**General**

- Question one
- Question two
- Question three

**Rules**

- Question four
- Question five
- Question six

**Payment**

- Question seven
- Question eight
- Question nine

... etc etc

Comment: Ok, so you can set up a template for your archive called archive-questions.php. Look up all "section" taxonomies associated with your questions CPT, then do a foreach loop where you output the section name as the heading, and do a query for all questions that have that particular taxonomy term set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code-

```
// Initiating shortcode. Place this code to any of your page to get your desired output.
add_shortcode( 'faq_page_content', 'the_dramatist_faq_page_content');
/**
 * Rendering function
 */
function the_dramatist_faq_page_content() {
    $terms = get_terms('sections'); // Taxonomy name
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        $posts = get_posts(
            array(
               'post_type' => 'questions', // Post type
               'tax_query' => array(
                   array(
                       'taxonomy' => 'sections', // Taxonomy name
                       'field' => 'slug',
                       'terms' => $term->slug
                   )
               ),
               'posts_per_page' => -1
            )
        );
        echo '<li>' . $term->name;
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($posts as $post) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Here we are initiating a shortcode called `faq_page_content`. Load this block of code through your plugin or `functions.php` and paste `[faq_page_content]` shortcode inside your desired page where you wanna show the FAQ's. You'll get your needed output.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's great, thanks! I've removed the function and just used it within the loop on the archive page, but it's good to see how it can be used as a shortcode, very useful.

Comment: Quick follow up. Is there anyway to output the content of each post? As the content (the answers to the questions in this case) are only one sentence I don't want to link to the post, I simply want to display it underneath. I tried `echo $post->post_content();` but this didn't work :(

Comment: Try it by removing the parenthesis. I mean like this - `$post->post_content`.

Comment: My last question on this - if I wanted to output only the questions related to a specific category such as 'Payment' is there a way to filter further down using the ID of that category?

Comment: I'm not clear about your question. Would you please elaborate it a little bit ? If you think that the comment form is not enough please feel free to ask another question with the above answer code and give me the link.

Comment: thanks, posted a follow up here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267543/filtering-custom-post-type-query